# How to use second host in a group when host 1 fails in ansible?

Tags: ansible, yaml, devops, ansible-2.x

I have an inventory with 500+ groups each having 2 hosts, 1 is primary and another one is secondary. In my playbook i am doing two things. One is taking the list of unreachable hosts and second is to execute a command in primary server.

My inventory example : (Like this i haave 500+ groups from set1...set500)

```
[set1]
host1set1 setup=primary
host2set1 setup=secondary
[set1:vars]
setidentifier=set1
```

I am able to collect the list of hosts that are not reachable and execute the command in primary server. **Now, i would like to know how to execute the command in the secondary server only if my primary server is not reachable.**

```
  - delegate_to: localhost
    command: ping -c1 "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_host|default(inventory_hostname) }}"
    register: ping
    ignore_errors: true
    become: false

  - set_fact:
     available: "{{ ping.rc == 0 }}"

  - lineinfile:
      dest: "/tmp/available.txt"
      line: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]. }} : {{ inventory_hostname }}"
      regexp: "Host: {{ inventory_hostname }}"
      create: true
    delegate_to: localhost
    become: false
    when: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].available }} == False"

  - shell: date
    register: dateout
    when: "setup is search('primary')"
```

I need to execute the shell task(i have mentioned date command just for reference, i have something else to do.) in the secondary server only when my primary server is not reachable.

Can someone throw some light here how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Ping the group first.  The unreachable hosts will be excluded from future plays:

Here's my inventory:

```
[groupA]
AnsibleTower ansible_host=192.168.124.8
[groupB]
jaxsat ansible_host=192.168.124.111
rhel7.5 ansible_host=192.168.124.4
```

Now, here's the playbook w/o ping:

```
---
- hosts: groupB
  gather_facts: no
  connection: ssh
  tasks:
  - name: Run hostname command
    command: /bin/hostname
    register: result
    run_once: yes 

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      var: result
    run_once: yes
```

It fails because `jaxsat` is off:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory/ test_one_only.yml

PLAY [groupB] **********************************************************************************

TASK [Run hostname command] ********************************************************************
Tuesday 21 July 2020  13:40:38 -0400 (0:00:00.064)       0:00:00.064 ********** 
fatal: [jaxsat]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 192.168.124.111 port 22: No route to host\r\n", "unreachable": true}
 [WARNING]: Failure using method (v2_runner_on_unreachable) in callback plugin
(<ansible.plugins.callback.mail.CallbackModule object at 0x7f95688fbf10>): [Errno 111]
Connection refused


NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *****************************************************************************
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/jack/Ansible/TEST/test_one_only.retry

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************
jaxsat                     : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   

Tuesday 21 July 2020  13:40:42 -0400 (0:00:03.218)       0:00:03.283 ********** 
=============================================================================== 
Run hostname command -------------------------------------------------------------------- 3.22s
Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 3 seconds
```

Now, I add the `ping`:

```
---
- hosts: groupB
  gather_facts: no
  connection: ssh
  tasks:
  - name: ping all hosts
    ping:

  - name: Run hostname command
    command: /bin/hostname
    register: result
    run_once: yes 

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      var: result
    run_once: yes
```

And `jaxsat` is not tried on other tasks:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory/ test_one_only.yml

PLAY [groupB] **********************************************************************************

TASK [ping all hosts] **************************************************************************
Tuesday 21 July 2020  13:42:12 -0400 (0:00:00.057)       0:00:00.057 ********** 
ok: [rhel7.5]
fatal: [jaxsat]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 192.168.124.111 port 22: No route to host\r\n", "unreachable": true}
 [WARNING]: Failure using method (v2_runner_on_unreachable) in callback plugin
(<ansible.plugins.callback.mail.CallbackModule object at 0x7f07f21ad850>): [Errno 111]
Connection refused


TASK [Run hostname command] ********************************************************************
Tuesday 21 July 2020  13:42:15 -0400 (0:00:03.217)       0:00:03.275 ********** 
changed: [rhel7.5]

TASK [Show result] *****************************************************************************
Tuesday 21 July 2020  13:42:15 -0400 (0:00:00.348)       0:00:03.623 ********** 
ok: [rhel7.5] => {
    "result": {
        "changed": true, 
        "cmd": [
            "/bin/hostname"
        ], 
        "delta": "0:00:00.001530", 
        "end": "2020-07-21 13:42:15.921749", 
        "failed": false, 
        "rc": 0, 
        "start": "2020-07-21 13:42:15.920219", 
        "stderr": "", 
        "stderr_lines": [], 
        "stdout": "localhost.localdomain.localdomain", 
        "stdout_lines": [
            "localhost.localdomain.localdomain"
        ]
    }
}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/jack/Ansible/TEST/test_one_only.retry

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************
jaxsat                     : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   
rhel7.5                    : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   

Tuesday 21 July 2020  13:42:15 -0400 (0:00:00.037)       0:00:03.661 ********** 
=============================================================================== 
ping all hosts -------------------------------------------------------------------------- 3.22s
Run hostname command -------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.35s
Show result ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.04s
Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 3 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You have pointed the play to run on hostB manually in your playbook. How do I do it ? I have 500+ groups and I won't be able to add the groups manually to the playbook right ?

Comment: Not HOSTB, but GROUPB.  Anyway, I assumed that you had different tasks for different groups.  (Otherwise, why are they in different groups?)

Comment: The task is same for all the groups. But the inventory is defined in that way.

Answer (score 0):

To perform task only on a single host from group - try using `run_once: true` for ansible task, detailed reference cab be find [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once)

If you know that master is reachable, the you can set a variable fact like `execute_on_secondary = False` for remaining hosts in a group and use it for when condition in `block` of tasks

```
- set_fact:
    execute_on_secondary: False
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ play_hosts }}"
  run_once: yes
  when: ## condition for when primary is reachable ##

- block:
    # tasks here
  when: setup == "primary" or execute_on_secondary
```

---

> Below way is very trivial. Test it well before using it on business critial system.

```
- hosts: all
  serial: 2
  tasks:
    - set_fact: ## same as above ##
      run_once: yes
    - block:
        # tasks here
      when: setup == "primary" or execute_on_secondary
```

Comment: This can be run only to one group isn't it ? If I run this job for all 500 groups at once(to my entire inventory) , this will run only in one group as we are using run_once right ?

Comment: @Rajesh If you are using `- hosts: all` in the playbook file, `run_once` will make that task run only on single host in `all` group (ansible does not process tasks on group by group basis, it processes a single special group called `all` that by default contains all hosts in the inventory). For more clarity on this try printing the `{{ groups }}` variable value using `debug` module in a playbook (do not forget to use `run_once` here, otherwise, that variable will be printed 500 times).

Comment: @Rajesh A trivial hack can work - if each host_group has only 2 host entries (one master and one secondary), the you can use `serial: 2` in the playbook to get the desired result. See second section in my answer above.